# Webdriverio execute custom command wait for async call on the browser side

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, webdriver, webdriver-io

I have one problem

Here is my custom command

```
 client.addCommand('getBinaryImage', function (message) {
            var self = this;
            return self.execute(
                function downloadImageBinary(url) {
                    var err = null;
                    var result = null;

                    function toDataURL(url, callback) {
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.onload = function () {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = function () {
                                callback(reader.result);
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
                        };
                        xhr.open('GET', url);
                        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                        xhr.send();
                    }

                    toDataURL(url, function (dataUrl) {
                        alert('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
                        // Now return the result !!
                    });
                }
            );
        });
```

And I am using it as follows

```
  let chain = client
                        .url("https://stackoverflow")
                        .getBinaryImage("image url here")
                        .then((result) => {
                            console.log(result);
                        })
```

But as you can see the execution of the script on the browsers side is async.

The problem is that I need to execute this script sync in the chain order, so until the result is not ready it should not reach the `then` handler in the chain.

Please suggest how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise that resolves only when you get your data back.
I'm using http://bluebirdjs.com as the promises library, they also have a nice and simple example over there - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html

wrap your entire function with
`return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {`

and when you get the result (your `// Now return the result !!` code) invoke `resolve(dataUrl)`

Comment: But how can I return promise from browser, AFAIK all communication is serialized

Comment: @bxfvgekd - it's asynchronous just like node.js code.
Just like the XHR function you're calling, which is async.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but when execute is called, it will send serialized script to the browser and execute it there and when the return statement is called it will serialize the result and send it back to the my node js app, and therefore it is a simple text and nothing more